# Simple Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models. A driver and a car. The driver can own many cars. A car can be owned by many drivers. Car Model `has_many :drivers, through: :car_ownership`. This works and everything is fine.

But I want to return all cars with drivers only, something like this:

```
@cars = Car.where.not(drivers: nil)
```

`Car.first.drivers` returns all a collection of Active Record Model Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this (assuming your `car_ownerships` table has a `driver_id` column):

```
Car.joins(:car_ownerships).where('car_ownerships.driver_id IS NOT NULL')
```

Using pure Active Record, this query would be:

```
Car.joins(:car_ownerships).where.not(car_ownerships: { driver_id: nil })
```

Comment: Yes this. Is there a way to do it in clean active record?

Comment: Try this please: `Car.joins(:car_ownerships).where.not(car_ownerships: { driver_id: nil })`

Comment: Awesome! You have a great day too :)